# ruby/rails - Given two Hashes how to exchange items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following hashes:

```
@valids
[
  {
    :lname => "Brown",
    :email => "james@intuit.com",
    :fname => "James"
  },
  {
    :lname => "Smith",
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => "Brad"
  }
]


@invalids
[
  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => nil
  },

  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "roger@gmail.com",
    :fname => nil
  }
]
```

What I'm going to be doing is looping through the invalids, and if an email meets a certain criteria, I want to move that item to valids and then remove it from invalids.

Example, while looping through @invalids, if the email = roger@gmail.com, I want to take:

```
  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "roger@gmail.com",
    :fname => nil
  }
```

And move it to @valids, and remove it from @invalids.

Is there a way to do this without having to create new hashes? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@invalids = @invalids.reject do |record|
  if record[:email] == "roger@gmail.com"
    @valids.push(record)
  end
end
```

To explain it a little bit, I'm setting @invalids as the result of running
@invalids.reject and passing it a block, so it will reject any array item that meets the criteria (returns something truish).

Inside the conditional I add to the @valids array